# How to use the lbfgs optimizer with pytorch-lightning?

Tags: pytorch

I have a problem in using the LBFGS optimizer from pytorch with lightning.
I use the template from [here](https://github.com/williamFalcon/pytorch-lightning-conference-seed) to start a new project and here is the code that I tried (only the training portion):

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
    x, y = batch
    x = x.float()
    y = y.float()
    y_hat = self.forward(x)
    return {'loss': F.mse_loss(y_hat, y)}

def configure_optimizers(self):
    optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(self.parameters())
    return optimizer

def optimizer_step(self, epoch_nb, batch_nb, optimizer, optimizer_i):
    def closure():
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        l = self.training_step(batch, batch_nb)
        loss = l['loss']
        loss.backward()
        return loss

    optimizer.step(closure)
```

The LBFGS optimizer from pytorch requires a closure function (see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lbfgs.html) and [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.LBFGS.step)), but I don't know how to define it inside the template, specially I don't know how the batch data is passed to the optimizer. I tried to define a custom optimizer_step function but I have some problems to passing the batch inside the closure function.

I will be very thankful of any advise that helps me to solve this problem or points me to the right direction.

Environment:

- PyTorch version:  1.2.0+cpu
- Lightning version: 0.4.9
- Test-tube version: 0.7.1

Comment: For future reference, this is now supported. See [#246](https://github.com/williamFalcon/pytorch-lightning/issues/246) and [#310](https://github.com/williamFalcon/pytorch-lightning/pull/310).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for lbfgs optimizer was added on [#310](https://github.com/williamFalcon/pytorch-lightning/pull/310), now it is not required to define a closure function.